# Euro short-term rate (€STR) question

Tags: short-rate, rates, interbank-rates, overnight-rate

Based on the latest data published by ECB,€STR = -0.56%. Is this the rate a bank would pay to borrow overnight or it's an annualised overnight rate so the actual overnight rate can be approximated with (1 - 0.56%)^(1/365) - 1?

Answer (score 1):

It is an annual rate, with a Actual/360 day count so the interest paid on an overnight loan is -0.56%/360.

Comment: thanks, are also the other overnight rates expressed in annual terms (eg SOFR,SONIA, SARON)?

Comment: Convention is to quote all interest rates on an annualized basis (not just overnight rates).

Comment: So for example also 6m Euribor, I would need to divide it by 2 to get the actual 6m rate?

Comment: The ‘rate’ is always annual.  The amount of interest on a 6 month rate quoted at 0.25% would be 0.25%* number of days /360

Comment: thanks understood. I was looking at the current Euribor rates ( https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/euribor/euribor.aspx) and it seems that longer tenors are more negative than shorter tenors (if I covert them from quote/annualised to actual). Why is this? Usually with bonds is the other way around where shorter tenors are more negative and long tenors (e.g. bunds curve)

Comment: You should look at them all on an annualized basis. Term structure of money market rates (largely) reflects monetary policy expectations hence it might up upward or downward sloping.